# Plotting several lines in a Chart

Tags: c#, mschart

I have 4 radio buttons. Each one of them corresponds to one type (columns in the DB) of the input temperature that I wanna use.

What do I already have:
If I choose one radio button + press Load - it plots the graph. If I choose again this button (or any of the other Radiobuttons) it plots in a sequence of the original graph.

What do I need help with:
I would like that each time that I press the button "Load" the Line would be "added" to the existing graph. In other words, I may have 4 different lines in the same graph, each one representing on radio button that I selected and pressed "Load."

Code:

```
private void BtnLoadDataToGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string column_to_use = "";
    double column_percentage_XX = 0;
    double column_percentage_XX = 0;
    string ReceiveNameFile = CboxReceiveNameFile.Text;


    if (RadioButtonStartXXTemp.Checked)
        column_to_use = "START_XX_TEMP";
    else if (RadioButtonStartXXTemp.Checked)
        column_to_use = "START_XX_TEMP";
    if (RadioButtonAvgTemp.Checked)
        column_to_use = "(START_XX_TEMP + START_XX_TEMP)/2";
    else
    {
        column_percentage_XX = Int32.Parse(TextBoxXXPercentage.Text);
        column_percentage_XX = (Convert.ToDouble(column_percentage_XX) / 100);

        column_percentage_XX = Int32.Parse(TextBoxXXPercentage.Text);
        column_percentage_XX = (Convert.ToDouble(column_percentage_XX) / 100);

        column_to_use = "(START_XX_TEMP*" + column_percentage_XX + ")+(START_XX_TEMP*" + column_percentage_XX + ")";
    }

    SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection("XXXXXX");
    SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand("select " + column_to_use + " AS temp,  SUBSTRING (header.TIME,CHARINDEX(' ',header.TIME,1),len(header.TIME)) as time,CONVERT(datetime,header.TIME,101) as new_time, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME),0,CHARINDEX('\\\',REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME)))) as folder_name from TBL_DATA_TYPE_RO_HEADER header,TBL_FILE_NAMES fnames,TBL_PROGRAM program where program.PK_ID_TBL_PROGRAM = fnames.FK_ID_TBL_PROGRAM and fnames.PK_ID_TBL_FILE_NAMES = header.FK_ID_TBL_FILE_NAMES and REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME),0,CHARINDEX('\\\',REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME))))='" + ReceiveNameFile + "'  order by new_time", conDatabase);

    SqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDatabase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            this.ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTemp"].Points.AddXY(myReader["time"].ToString(), myReader["temp"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how can I do this? I was thinking in maybe use "Points.Aggregate" instead of "Points.AddXY". But I don't think that it is the right path especially because each radiobutton should has a different color line.

Any help or tips are welcome!

Comment: Not sure what you want but maybe you want to have 4 series instead of only 1?

Comment: Hey @TaW , yes, I wanna have in the same graph several lines (several series of values)

Comment: Well, then add more Series and add to their respetive Points collections! This is rather straight-forward..

Comment: @TaW , my problem is that if I press "Load Data", it is creating a sequence of series. In other words, if I press 3 times the "Load Data", the series are being add in sequence in the graph and not in the same place. Trying to explain better, if I press Load 2 times, I will have in the graph 2 same series in sequence of each other ("splitting the graph in 2").
I need that when I press Load, it Loads the graphs in the same position of the original.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you do. Sp far all I see is one Series called "TimeVsTemp", but you need more and of course you should add the series you want only once, when you set up the chart..

Comment: Radiobuttons are a bad choice if you want to allow the display of several data groups. Checkboxes are what yu should use! - Also: Instead of a Reader Filling a DataTable would be more natural, imo..

Answer (score 0):

`this.ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTemp"].Points.AddXY(myReader["time"].ToString(), myReader["temp"].ToString());`

This line is always plotting your data on the same series.  You need to make a new series each time you press the load button.  Something like:

```
private void BtnLoadDataToGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string column_to_use = "";
        double column_percentage_XX = 0;
        double column_percentage_XX = 0;
        string ReceiveNameFile = CboxReceiveNameFile.Text;


        if (RadioButtonStartXXTemp.Checked)
            column_to_use = "START_XX_TEMP";
        else if (RadioButtonStartXXTemp.Checked)
            column_to_use = "START_XX_TEMP";
        if (RadioButtonAvgTemp.Checked)
            column_to_use = "(START_XX_TEMP + START_XX_TEMP)/2";
        else
        {
            column_percentage_XX = Int32.Parse(TextBoxXXPercentage.Text);
            column_percentage_XX = (Convert.ToDouble(column_percentage_XX) / 100);

            column_percentage_XX = Int32.Parse(TextBoxXXPercentage.Text);
            column_percentage_XX = (Convert.ToDouble(column_percentage_XX) / 100);

            column_to_use = "(START_XX_TEMP*" + column_percentage_XX + ")+(START_XX_TEMP*" + column_percentage_XX + ")";
        }

        SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection("XXXXXX");
        SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand("select " + column_to_use + " AS temp,  SUBSTRING (header.TIME,CHARINDEX(' ',header.TIME,1),len(header.TIME)) as time,CONVERT(datetime,header.TIME,101) as new_time, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME),0,CHARINDEX('\\\',REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME)))) as folder_name from TBL_DATA_TYPE_RO_HEADER header,TBL_FILE_NAMES fnames,TBL_PROGRAM program where program.PK_ID_TBL_PROGRAM = fnames.FK_ID_TBL_PROGRAM and fnames.PK_ID_TBL_FILE_NAMES = header.FK_ID_TBL_FILE_NAMES and REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME),0,CHARINDEX('\\\',REVERSE(fnames.PATH_NAME))))='" + ReceiveNameFile + "'  order by new_time", conDatabase);

        SqlDataReader myReader;

        conDatabase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

        Series s = new Series();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            s.Points.AddXY(myReader["time"].ToString(), myReader["temp"].ToString());
        }

        chart1.Series.Add(s);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new series in the chart and add the new points into it